# sed text replace

Tags: sed, base64

How can I replace text with other text using GNU sed? I was hacked and am just trying to see if I can remove some of the code that was placed into my php files. The text is of the

```
eval(base64_decode('blah'));
```

variety. All of them are identical, I would just like to find and replace all of them in all files. I have tried some commands, but they either needlessly alter and damage text in the files or simply fail to launch at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed command text replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947841/sed-command-text-replace)

Comment: That discussion fizzled out, this one worked it out, I voted to delete the other one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hacked Site - SSH to remove a large body of javascript from 200+ files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407263/hacked-site-ssh-to-remove-a-large-body-of-javascript-from-200-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/text/other text/g' filename
```

(`sed -i "s/eval(base64_decode('blah'))/huh/g" filename` in your case).

Comment: Thanks, I tried to escape some things. I entered `sed -i 's/eval\(base64_decode\(\"DQplyI0KfQ==\"\)\)\;//g' filename/dir/*`    and it returned `sed: -e expression #1, char 1195: unknown option to [*backtick*]s'`

Comment: I don't think in this particular string you need any escaping.

Comment: OK, no escaping, still returned with sed: -e expression #1, char 1188: unknown option to `s'

Comment: I thought you wanted all files?

Comment: @notam2774, But in your example there're no slashes in text?

Answer (score 1):

`find . -name \*.php -exec sed -i "s/text/other/g" {} \;`

You may want to do a dry run and leave off the -i and just direct it to a file as a test first.

On Mac the -i usually doesn't work.