# Hacked Site - SSH to remove a large body of javascript from 200+ files

Tags: javascript, apache, ssh, code-injection

I have been asked to clean a hacked site on apache (php, JS, HTML) which I can do and I have implemented security features, however there is still JS injected into about 2000+ javascript files. The injected code is the same on every page and about 5500 characters long with !'' characters interspersed.

Ideally I'd like to run a SSH command that would find and remove this long code from every page it is on. All of the examples find, grep, sed etc only show it for very short strings with no special characters.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I can't imagine not simply restoring from uncontaminated backup versions, and completely rebuilding all servers involved.

Comment: honestly, just restore from a backup. The injected js was very likely overwriting parts of your code.

Comment: And the hacker might have installed backdoors. Wipe the server, clean install and redeploy the site from version control. Maybe you can suggest your client to use [infrastructure as code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code), so that will be easier the next time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grepping variables containing special characters in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261427/grepping-variables-containing-special-characters-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: It *is* possible to remove clean code from an infected website/server, without wiping. Sysadmins have to do this where there are insufficient backups, normally against advice.

Answer (score 4):

There's no point to trying to fix the server in-place.  Wipe it down to bare metal and re-deploy from source control.

Once someone has gotten into your boxes, there's no way to ensure they're really gone unless you burn it all down.  There's certainly no magic command that can figure it out for you.

Comment: Brad is 100% right here. There are specialist tools available to perform the wipe process. Even if there is no source control, remove the code from the server, wipe server. Then work on code recovery.

Comment: Use `Deft 8.2` from USB to boot and wipe using the command `dc3dd`